# HttpStatusCodeResult status description not sent to the client

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, axios

I am making an AJAX POST request to an ASP.Net MVC controller. From there I have to send an error status code of 400 or 500 with a message like the following:

```csharp
// MVC Controller
return new HttpStatusCodeResult(500, "Error message");
```

The problem is in the Javascript where I catch the error; it will only return the status code and an empty `statusText`. I have no idea why.

```js
// Javascript
let data = $('.jsCheckoutForm').serialize() + '&' + $.param(additionVal);

axios.post(url, data).then(function(result) {
  if (result.status != 200) {
    notification.error(result);
  } else {
    $('#paymentBlock').html(result.data);
    feather.replace();
    inst.initPayment();
  }
}).catch(function(error) {
  if (error.response.status == 400) {
    $("#giftcard-alert").html(error.response.statusText);
  } else {
    notification.error(error);
  }
}).finally(function() {
  $('.loading-box').hide();
});
```

Comment: Where is your JS code where you attempt to read the error message from the response?